# databinding not working in simple Knockoutjs application

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to learn KO and when I write this is in a html, the input text box doesn't have the value on the load. Can some one help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="C:\Data\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\KObasics\Scripts\knockout-3.4.2.debug.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
<input  data-bind="value:firstName"/>
<p data-bind="text:firstName"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your javascript file to after the main html body?

Comment: @M.Ihsan Sorry I cant understand

Comment: I posted the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html and javascript looks ok, as it is working fine below.

```js
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = "Bert";
  this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
<input  data-bind="value:firstName"/>
<p data-bind="text:firstName"></p>
```

You just need to move the `<script>` tag to the end of `<body>` element before the closing tag (`</body>`). To make sure the DOM element are rendered before those are bind to the knockout model. It'll be like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="C:\Data\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\KObasics\Scripts\knockout-3.4.2.debug.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
<input  data-bind="value:firstName"/>
<p data-bind="text:firstName"></p>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand and will use jquery document ready function to bind it.

Comment: That will do the job as well :)